# How this input and output for Hadoop works?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I just setup my single node Hadoop cluster on my local machine using this tutorial -

http://ac31004.blogspot.com/2013/10/installing-hadoop-2-on-mac_29.html

In this tutorial I followed this following instructions :
try  a ls
hadoop fs -ls

if you get

ls: `.': No such file or directory

then there is no home directory in the hadoop file system.  So

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<username>
```

where is the name you are logged onto the machine with.

now change to $HADOOP_INSTALL directory and upload a file

```
hadoop fs -put LICENSE.txt
```

When I used this following command :

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0 wordcount LICENSE.txt out
```

It worked but I am not able to find the output folder. So to debug I tried to use another output folder and used :

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0 wordcount LICENSE.txt  /Applications/hadoop-2.2.0/out2
```

This worked fine, but the problem is I don`t seethe directory out2 in the application folder.

Then I created a directory 'in' in the /Applications/hadoop-2.2.0 and put README.txt in it and tried to use following command :

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /Applications/hadoop-2.2.0/in/README.txt  /Applications/hadoop-2.2.0/out3
```

Now I got an error:

> ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:chinmay (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/Applications/hadoop-2.2.0/in/README.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input and output folders are also on HDFS. Create them there, not on the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. So, I have to upload all my files to hdfs before processing them.
I have a another question that, I am able to browse and see my outputs through:
http://localhost:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/&nnaddr=127.0.0.1:9000

But, is it possible for me to see them in the hadoop directory ? If yes, then which directory is the directory 'out' created is stored ?

thanks

Comment: Use the hadoop fs commands to view your hdfs files. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html